# Thread-specific data

Tags: c

If we want to use thread specific data in a multithreaded application, how to access those data from another collector thread periodically? Is it possible?

Regards
Ram

Comment: What operating system are you targeting?

Comment: It is for all flavors. But i think it will be good if i get for Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all the threads in the process (application) share the same memory. Just give the address  of the data to the collector thread. Be careful with concurrent access: reading some parts of the memory while it's being updated. You might need to protect some memory zones with mutex.

Comment: Thanks! So do you mean that, we need to put addresses allocated in all threads for my data in a common list or something, where the collector thread can go and refer, access and fetch data? In a synchrnoized way?

Comment: Yes, or you can pass the address[es] to your collector thread when you create it.

Answer (score 0):

Under certain systems it is possible to create variables in so-called **thread-local storage**.  [Gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.4/gcc/Thread_002dLocal.html) explains how you can achieve it and provides the link to Drepper's article, that explains technical details.  This is a C standard extension, so under your system there should be a different mechanism.

Comment: It seems to be very infromative. THanks a lot. I will have a look at it.